# hokuyo_node sending 0.0 measurements -> problems with costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

we are using a Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 laser scanner on our robot. The scanner has a range of max. 5.6m. Now we ran into some problems in the environment we are in, which is kind of a living room/office environment and has distances >5.6m.

We observed, that when the distance that should be measured by the laser scanner is greater 5.6m, the hokuyo_node publishes a range of 0.0. As I understand it, this shouldn't happen, since the minimal distance in the documentation of the scanner is 20mm.

This then in turn leads to problems with the costmap, because due to the 0.0 measurements, the costmap doesn't get cleared, when the laser sees nothing within it's range.

Has anyone of you observed the same problem and/or can provide a not too hacky solution?

Thank you very much.

Kind regards,
Matthias

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36785/hokuyo_node-sending-0.0-measurements--%3E-problems-with-costmap/) by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 12390 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Refer to my question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/30014/costmap-clearing-of-obstacles/). The usual way seems to be to use [laser filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_filters). But for my own case, I just altered the scans at the driver level since I'm not in need of the 0.0 readings anyway. Of course, remember to make a copy of the hokuyo_node for your own code, since the one in ros stacks may be overwritten during updates.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0